# How to add amounts for the first instance of the order number

Tags: r

I have about 79 columns in the dataframe but for the purposes of this question, only 4 are required.

[image]

“ ORD # “ is a unique identifier that can be used to count how many orders were placed and “QTY” indicates the total number of individual items ordered. However, only one instance of an ORD # has to be taken into account so in the picture for example, ORD # 1620404 should count as 1 order even if it appeared two times and ORD # 1620753; this order appears once in the report but has a QTY of 39. This means 1620753 should count as 39 orders.
I need to group these by Manager and by month and year to see how many they ordered Month to date and year to date

the code i have come up with so far is like this coming up with a mixture of first in the dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)

#MTD

Testing<-InvoiceReportWithoutNA %>% 
  group_by(Month=month(`ORDER DATE`),`Manager`)%>% 
  mutate(QTYMonthManager = sum(first(QTY), by=`ORD #`)%>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Please don't add data as images, add them as `dput`. Read how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me why you select 1 and 39 in two orders. Is it because they are `max` value in that order or because they are the `first` value? Based on your attempt I'll assume you select them because they are the `first` value.

Additionally, there is no `by` argument in `mutate`, add the `ORD #` in `group_by`. Try :

```
library(dplyr)

InvoiceReportWithoutNA %>% 
   group_by(Year_Month = format(`ORDER DATE`, '%Y-%m'), Manager) %>% 
   mutate(QTYMonthManager = sum(QTY[!duplicated(`ORD #`)]))
```

Comment: Yes - that would be the first instance. This works - Thanks. What if i want to keep all rest of the columns and rows so essentially it will just create another column and i can see MTD for all the managers.

Comment: Use `mutate` insted of `summarise` ?

Comment: actually, If i use mutate, it's not adding the first instance, just copying the QTY, would you know how to go around this?

Comment: Maybe you have `plyr` loaded with `dplyr`. Try with `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: Didn't work, i don't think i explained it well.  So in the picture that i provided for example, the total value of orders that Adam Smith would have ordered would be (1 + 39 + 2 + 3) 45 orders in the month of Jan so it will show as 45 on all the rows in the QTYMonthManager column.

Comment: So you want to `sum` the `QTY` column. I have updated the answer, please check .

Comment: but your edit is grouping by ORD #. I only want to group by manager and the month. Just want an additional column that will add the QTY of all ORD # per manager per month in its first instance because there maybe duplicates of ord # which i don't want to count

Comment: Added another edit. Maybe it will give what you want.